# I need an autohotkey script that will left mouse click at a specific time of day

Tags: autohotkey

I need a script that will left mouse click at a specific time of day. I found the following (see link) which is working but was wondering if there is now simpler code (this code is old ) that will do the same? I will be at the computer and can position the mouse so I won't need x, y coordinates. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I copied the code from here:

https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/485-need-to-program-a-left-mouse-click-to-run-at-a-certain-time/

Code:

```
#persistent

TargetTime = 1800



StringLeft, TargetDateTime, A_Now, 8   ; Put just YYYYMMDD into the 
variable.
TargetDateTime = %TargetDateTime%%TargetTime%
TimeUntilTarget = %TargetDateTime%
TimeUntilTarget -= %A_Now%, seconds
if TimeUntilTarget < 0
{
 MsgBox The target time is already past!
 return
}
TimeUntilTarget *= 1000 ; Convert to milliseconds.
TimeUntilTarget -= 1000
SetTimer, ClickTimer, %TimeUntilTarget%
return

ClickTimer:
SetTimer, ClickTimer, off  ; i.e. do only one click
MouseClick, left
```

Comment: I'm confused why you care about simpler code if this code works?

Comment: I can't find any information related to TargetDateTime and TimeUntilTarget. I am thinking that is old coding. How did the original author of the code know how to use those variables?